# Dynamically create a c# generic type with self referenced constraints

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, reflection.emit

I have a generic type that look like this

```
public class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>{ ... }
```

and I need to dynamically construct the type T.  So that it looks like this:

```
public class MyClass : Entity<MyClass>{ ... }
```

Can this be done ?

Comment: Was the reuse of "T" on purpose?  Would "public class MyClass : Entity<MyClass>{}" be the same?

Comment: No, MyClass would have been a better name.

Comment: What would the value be in "dynamically constructing" such a derived type over simply defining it directly:

public class MyEntity : Entity<MyEntity> {}

Comment: I am working on data binding of "Entity" objects.  The property descriptors of the "Entity" object depends on its factory class.  But when using a custom TypeDescriptionProvider, the property descriptors are returned based on Type.  Therefore I have no choice but to dynamically create wrapper types and associate it with its instance of factory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("TestAssembly");
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name);

TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyClass", TypeAttributes.Public);

Type entityType = typeof(Entity<>).MakeGenericType(typeBuilder);

typeBuilder.SetParent(entityType);


Type t = typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

Comment: Code snippet above assumes the class Entity<T> is already defined.

Comment: I didn't know TypeBuilder itself is actually a Type too!